# How to cancel sending requests if new requests are incoming?

Tags: javascript

I have a section with files. Each file can be moved one position higher or lower with an arrow. Currently a request is sent to the database every time that the user moves a file, and new order updated. So if the user wants to move the bottom file to the top, clicks the 'up' arrow 10 times, 10 requests will be sent.

How can I send fewer requests than that?

My first idea was to create request with order numbers, wait 1 second, create second request and if they are the same (the user hasn't continued to change the order), then send it, if not, wait another second and compare again. But this doesn't seem to be a good thing to do. Are there any other ways?

```
$ctrl.saveFileOrder = function() {
  var firstRequest = [];  

  for(var i = 0; 1 < $ctrl.fileArray.length; i++) {
    firstRequest.push({$ctrl.fileArray[i].id, $ctrl.fileArray[i].orderNumber});
  }

  var secondRequest = [];

  while(firstRequest != secondRequest) {
    //put thread to sleep for 1 second here

    for(var i = 0; 1 < $ctrl.fileArray.length; i++) {
      secondRequest.push({$ctrl.fileArray.id[i], $ctrl.fileArray.orderNumber[i]});
    }
  }

  //send the final request
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `disable` the button until a response has been received from the server so that the user cannot click again before the DB has been updated.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.js-move');

/**
 * Simulation of a request with a 2 second duration
 */
const sendRequest = value => new Promise(resolve => {
  console.log(`Updating to DB: ${value}`);
  buttons.forEach(button => button.disabled = true);
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('Update done');
    buttons.forEach(button => button.disabled = false);
    resolve();
  }, 2000);
});

buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', event => {
    const { value } = event.target;
    sendRequest(value);
  });
});
```

```html
<button class="js-move" value="-1">Move up</button>
<button class="js-move" value="+1">Move down</button>
```

Alternatively you are looking for a *throttle* function which, like the name suggest, bottlenecks the amount of calls by a specified amount set by you. So only once every second could you make a new request.

```js
const throttle = (callback, wait, immediate = false) => {
  let timeout = null;
  let initialCall = true;
  
  return (...args) => {
    const callNow = immediate && initialCall
    const next = () => {
      callback(...args);
      timeout = null;
    }
    
    if (callNow) { 
      initialCall = false;
      next();
    }

    if (!timeout) {
      timeout = setTimeout(next, wait);
    }
  }
}

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.js-move');

/**
 * Mock function where you send a request.
 */
const sendRequest = value => {
  console.log(`Updating to DB: ${value}`);
}

/**
 * Create throttled version of your request.
 * The number indicates the interval in milliseconds between
 * calling the sendRequest function.
 */
const throttledRequest = throttle(sendRequest, 1000, true);

buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', event => {
    const { value } = event.target;
    throttledRequest(value);
  });
});
```

```html
<button class="js-move" value="-1">Move up</button>
<button class="js-move" value="+1">Move down</button>
```

Comment: There is no problem with sending multiple requests, I just want to minimize their amount.

Comment: I've added another option for you to look at.